# Dealing with CSS specificity and the JavaScript that throws it off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am usually quite familiar with specificity and have no issue styling nested components. I have embarrassingly spent hours trying to access the "ul#dropMe" dropdown list in the below code. The code is essentially a bootstrap dropdown using a jquery scrolling plugin. My suspicion is that the JS throws the specificity off because after doing Inspect Element on the run webpage a div wrapper forms around the "ul#dropMe" to account for the scrollbar. I have tried numerous targeting css lines factoring in and out the new wrapper including "ul#dropMe", "div.scroll-wrapper ul#dropMe", etc.

If someone can provide insight I would greatly appreciate it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

      <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="scrolldown.css" >
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.scrollbar.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">

      <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/394d590898.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
      <script src="scrolldown.js"></script>

  </head>     

<body>

    <div class="container" id="dropdownContainer">
        <div class="dropdown" id = "drop">
            <button class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownButton" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              <div id="buttonText">Select</div>
              <i class="fa fa-angle-down angleDownIcon" ></i>
            </button>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdownMenu scrollbar-inner" id="dropMe" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuSelecter">
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Lorem</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Dolor</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Sit</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Amet</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Dolor</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Sit</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Amet</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Ipsum</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Dolor</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Sit</a></li>
                <li><a class="ddSelect"> Amet</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The CSS

```
.container
{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/***********************/
#dropdownContainer
{
  height: 300px;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.dropdownLabel 
{
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 16px;
  font: bold 14px 'Roboto',Arial;
  color: #555555;
}

#dropdownButton
{
  height: 34px;
  width: 173px; /*width set for demo*/
  max-width: 33%;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  margin:0px 10px 0px 16px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  border: solid 1px #DBDBDB;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #555555;

}

#dropdownButton div
{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  font: 14px 'Roboto',Arial;
  padding-top: 7px;
  float: left;
  color: #999999;
} 

#drop #dropMe
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 190px;
  height: 140px;
  padding: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
  margin: -34px 0px 0px 16px; 
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: rgb(219,219,219);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  box-shadow: 0px 9px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

ul.dropdownMenu li
{
  display: block;
  height: 34px;
  line-height: 34px;
  width: 171px;
}

/*didnt do padding top up because its autoset to fill the height of 34px which should be it.*/
ul.dropdownMenu li a
{ 
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 7.5px 10px 7.5px 10px;
  margin: 0px 0px -16px 0px;

  font: 14px "Roboto",Arial;
  color: #555555;
}

ul.dropdownMenu li a
{
  height: 34px;
}

.dropdownMenu li a:hover 
{
  background-color: #F7F7F7;    
}

.fa.fa-angle-down.angleDownIcon, .fa.fa-angle-up.angleUpIcon
{
  display: inline;
  float: right; 
  margin-right:0px; 
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: #999999;
}
```

The JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.scrollbar-inner').scrollbar();
});

$("a").click(function(event) 
{
   if ($(event.target).attr('class') == "ddSelect")
   {
        (document.getElementById('buttonText').innerHTML) = (event.target.textContent);
   }
});
```

Comment: This may not fix your problem, but you should remove the semicolon here:  `if ($(event.target).attr('class') == "ddSelect");`.  Otherwise, the block that follows will always run.

Comment: Dang yeah I removed it, but it seems that that was inconsequential to accessor issue as that it just a trivial function that updates the button text to what is on the clicked item.

Comment: Yeah my phrasing is just to be clear which componenet I'm referring to. Oh I would image that #drop #dropMe would be more specific since that's a parent's specific child selector. Regardless, neither target #dropMe.

Comment: Aside -- It will have more specificity https://jsfiddle.net/z9jrgsmx/1/